# Brew + PHP 7 + XDebug Not showing

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug

I have problem with x-debug in brew, if i type `php -v` show me this :

[image]

But when in .php file i use `phpinfo();` then there is no x-debug extension. so because of this i am not able to debug file in phpstorm.

Answer (score -1):

You have to restart your php-fpm service in mosts cases.

find if fpm-service is running by this :

`lsof -i -P`

Example : PID 901

Use :

```
kill 901
```

Restart PHP-FPM Service :

```
sudo php70-fpm start
```

or You can direct use `sudo php70-fpm restart` but i found some issue while running this so mostly i use to kill first then start again.